# Parsing XML in Python and my 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'len'

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm very new to Python and trying to write a program that parses some XML. I'm having the issue where when I attempt to call `.len()` on what I believe to be a NodeList I get the error `'NodeList' object has no attribute 'len'`. This is really surprising to me because the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html) says:

> In addition, the Python DOM interface requires that some additional support is provided to  allow NodeList objects to be used as Python sequences. All NodeList implementations must include support for **len**()

Here's my code:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

def testFunction(translationDOM):
    textCollection = translationDOM.getElementsByTagName("onscreen_text")
    for onscreenText in textCollection:
        print textCollection.len()
```

and then in the `Main()`...

```
translationDom  = parse(xmlFileName)
testFunction(translationDom)
```

I don't want to post my entire xml here (its massive), but there's a number of blocks similar to:

```
<onscreen_text>
    <source id="2036" unique_name="blah" should_be_translated="True">
    ....
 </onscreen_text>
```

Here's the full error text:

```
  File "trophytool.py", line 155, in <module>
    main()
  File "trophytool.py", line 134, in main
    testFunction(translationDom)
  File "trophytool.py", line 64, in testFunction
    print textCollection.len()
AttributeError: 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'len'
```

You'd think it would print the number of `<onscreen_text>` tags it finds, but it doesn't. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
print len(textCollection)
```

Explanation: Support for `len` usually means a class implements the `__len__()` method (not `len()`), which in turn allows you to call `len(object)`.

Answer (score 1):

The method getElementsByTagName() always returns a list, even if there is only one item.
For example in the next xml

```
<school>
   <department />
</school>
```

if you have the pointer to the "school" tag and you call

```
myNode.getElementsByTagName("department")
```

it will returns a list of nodes of lenght one

If you are sure that the call to the method getElementsByTagName() will return only one item you could do this instead of the above statement

```
myNode.getElementsByTagName("department").item(0)
```

and it will return a single node instead of a list of nodes with only one node.